# Open Source Bitcoin Trading Software

Tags: trading, open-source

Does anyone know if someone has created an open source (preferrably LAMP/PHP based) software package so that they can bring up their own BTC to ?currency? trading site?

I would love to be the guy getting 2% to 3% on transactions. And then I'd be responsible for server uptime and availability, fraud checks, APIs running smoothly, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersango is on Github.  Here is a thread on a forum on how to set up your own bitcoin exchange - https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=35812.0

Comment: OMG WAY COOL. Must tell my boss, who got me into this stuff.